# P(ABC) = P(AB) * P(BC) ? How can I prove it?

Tags: statistics

I am studying statistics, but I don't know weather below equation is true or not. please help me. T_T

P(ABC) = P(AB) * P(BC)

Thank you~

Comment: What are which here?  Please define the symbols you use. ABC are...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are the events "heads" of independent, identically distributed fair coins.

$P(ABC) = \text{The probability of all three coins landing heads up.} = \frac 1 8$

$P(AB) = \text{The probability of all first two coins landing heads up.} = \frac 1 4$

$P(BC) = \text{The probability of all last two coins landing heads up.} = \frac 1 4$

$P(AB) P(BC) = \frac 1 4 \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 {16} \neq \frac 1 8$

Comment: @DaeyongJin If you like the answer, hit the checkmark to the left to accept it.